# What is the best way to have an always accessible screen on iPad?

Tags: ios, ipad, tablet

I'm building an iPad app that has a slide out menu with several sections that can be drilled down. Just a generic iPad app.

However, there is a screen (let's call it Screen AA) that I would like to open at any point possible in the app. For now, it's in the slide out menu, but the slide out menu is not always accessible, so Screen AA is not always accessible.

Do you have any ideas where I can put a "button" (or some kind of trigger) that will open Screen AA no matter where I am in the app?

I know that many a tab bar can be used, but I decided not to use tab bar the app because of the real estate space it occupies.

NOTE: Screen AA has to be shown full screen as there is a lot of information on it.

Comment: Without seeing the screens, there's really no way for us to answer this other than 'put the button in an out-of-the-way-but-visible location'.

Comment: Have you got any space in the nav bar right hand side?

Comment: Yes, the app is in landscape mode so plenty of space. However, there is almost always an action button on the farthest right hand side of the nav bar.

Answer (score 1):

> but the slide out menu is not always accessible

Is there a specific reason for this? Is screen AA the only screen that needs to be accessed at any time?

You may want to consider having your slide out menu available at all times. This creates a persistent navigation, and will make it much easier for your users to navigate through your application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this would work in the context of your app, but maybe have the AA screen slide in from the right (or top, or bottom).  This behavior is simple it wouldn't be obvious and would require teaching with something like initial start-up instructions or a opaque overlay that says "Slide left for AA screen".  The opaque overlay instructions would disappear after the user does it 3 times, the assumption being that the behavior is now understood.

Answer (score 0):

The AA Screen is accessed by index finger stroke from left bottom corner. The control in the corner could be semitransparent. Also it could be used as small notification area for taking user's attention to switch to the AA Screen.
[image: quick access]

Comment: Ah but with the slide out menu assuming that it come from the left, this would need to move with the top level screens

Answer (score 0):

As other users have pointed out, it would be better if we could have some context as to what will be appearing.

Perhaps something like [Facebook's Chatheads](http://screenshots.en.sftcdn.net/blog/en/2013/04/facebook-messenger-for-android-chat-heads.png) would be a suitable idea? Simply having a circle with a menu icon, which could easily be moved around to stop from obstructing anything.